# Setting Multiple Text Views Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, textview

I have pairs of Text Views that I am setting beside each other, and also I need to layout them vertically as well unfortunately I have one area that will not set right which is txtView2 as per the code at the bottom.  If you look at the To View Fuel Stations the Click Here is drawn over it.  What did I miss here?  Here is my screen Shot.

[image]

And here is my code for the layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView  android:id="@+id/txtViewGPS"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="" 
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColorLink="#FFFF00"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView  android:id="@+id/txtView_5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtViewGPS"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColorLink="#FFFF00"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1_1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:text="To view Evacuation Routes - "
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

<TextView  android:id="@+id/txtView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1_1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
<TextView  android:id="@+id/txtView1_5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtView1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColorLink="#FFFF00"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>  
 <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2_1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtView1_5"
    android:text="To view shelters - "
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
<TextView  android:id="@+id/txtView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtView1"
    android:text="" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView2_1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
<TextView  android:id="@+id/txtView2_5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtView2_1"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColorLink="#FFFF00"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>  
 <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3_1" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtView2_5"
    android:text="To view Fuel Stations  - "
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>
<TextView  android:id="@+id/txtView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView3_1"
    android:text="" 
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you give them meaningful `id`s or at least point out which is which, it will be easier to help you. Meaningful `id`s may benefit you as well when you are writing the code

Comment: txtView2 and txtView2_1 are the id's giving me problems, txtView2_1 displays To view Fuel Stations, and txtView2 displays Click Here

Comment: txtView2_1 (from what you have here) is not the TextView that displays "To view Fuel Stations"

Comment: You have to much going on at once and your going to give yourself a headache. break it down into simpler task. Use a table or List to organize/arrange your displayed information then remove the "click here links" and turn your title text into links. Better that way and much simpler and less code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change your RelativeLayout to either a TableLayout or a vertical LinearLayout with 3 horizontal LinearLayouts. RelativeLayouts are more cumbersome than necessary for a simple implementation like this.

**TableLayout example:**

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="To view Evacuation Routes - "
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="To view Fuel Stations  - "
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="To view shelters - "
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

**LinearLayout example:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="To view Evacuation Routes - "
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="To view Fuel Stations  - "
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="To view shelters - "
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you give me a example?

Comment: no idea what/where you want the extra textviews, but per your image, i've added examples

Comment: Sorry about the slow reponse vertigo but this did it.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile users are used to clicking on whole areas (like list items). I would recommend getting rid of the "click here" links and just make the whole text clickable. Then you can just put them all in a vertical LinearLayout or in a ListView.

Comment: That's not at all an answer that's an opinion.

Comment: this depends on the context. maybe the text is shown in a help/about page, and the user can click on links there.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution isn't good from the beginning, because you've trying to use 2 textView instead of one. think what would happen if the screen can't hold them both, or if the user has set to use larger fonts for the OS.

Here's some possible solutions:

1. use 2 textviews anyway, and a custom made layout (like [flowLayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)) . not recommended as it will take the whole parts of the textViews instead of words.
2. use a single textView and [Html.fromHtml](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) and handle clicked on the links.
3. use a webView to show HTML content and handle clicking on the links. not recommnded as the webView has weird issues with scrolling, especially if it's inside a container that is scrollable.

BTW, you should put your strings in the strings.xml. it's especially good for localization.

Answer (score 0):

txtView2 is set up to display to the right of txtView2_1, when it should be set up to display to the right of txtView3_1 (To view Fill Stations).

You do need to name your IDs better, though. It's too confusing as is.

Comment: he could use the graphical designer and drag things there. it's usually easier to use when you use the relativeLayout. after that, he can rename the ids by using ALT+SHIFT+R .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work but give it a try. My comment may have been confusing to read.

Try removing `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView2_1"` of `textView2` and add to it

```
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"  <!-- or whatever is the id of the one above this one
```